# coldfusion query output data after todays date

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a CFquery that displays entries by from todays date onwards, the trouble is, its using the day to order the results, instead of ordering them by the while date?

The date format is in uk dd/mm/yyy

```
    <cfquery name="GetDates" datasource="#session.odbcname#">
SELECT  *
FROM    infodata,courses
WHERE   course_id = #url.course_id#
AND infodata.coursename = courses.course_dantename
AND infodata.StartDate > <cfqueryparam value="#createODBCDate(now())#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> 


ORDER BY infodata.StartDate
```

The startDate variable is in the dd/mm/yyyy format but the results are displaying as follows…

- 10/06/2014
- 06/09/2014
- 20/10/2014
- 22/09/2014
- 23/06/2014

They are order by day instead of date as such and I need them by date?

Any ideas very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please confirm the datatype of infodata.startdate.  Not related to your question, but the createodbcdate() function is not required.  You can send now() as the value of the parameter.

Comment: Hi Dan the datatype is set to varchar

Comment: sadly, I can't use the datatype 'date time' as the data is being pulled from an XML file.

Comment: That is your problem. The values are being sorted as strings, not dates. The optimal solution is to store the values in a `date/time` column. It is better for both data integrity and performance. *RE: can't use the datatype 'date time'* Why not? You should be able to convert/cast the input as dates. What exactly is the process, and which dbms?

Answer (score 3):

Change your query so that it includes:

```
select blah, blah, something that casts your string to a date as thedate
etc
order by thedate
```

How you cast your string to a date depends on your database engine, which you didn't specify.  For example, oracle has a to_date() function, mysql has a str_to_date function, etc.

To be thorough, you'll want to change your where clause as well.

Regarding this comment, "sadly, I can't use the datatype 'date time' as the data is being pulled from an XML file".  That's not entirely true.  You can load your xml data into a staging table, process as necessary, and write to your real tables from your staging table.  There are a lot of advantages to this approach.  Converting strings to date times is only one of them.

Comment: Hi Dan, many thanks for your feedback, a staging table sounds good as there are other bits of data in there that could do with cleaning up as well. However, i'm not experienced enough to even know where to start on that one - any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: A google search on "database staging tables" will get you started.  Since you have ColdFusion at work here, another consideration you are going to have to account for is the concept of simultaneous use.  If that's conceivable, you might want to use temporary tables to stage your data.  Like functions, the details behind that concept depend on the database.